# Butterworth filter

Tags: power-electronics, filter, digital-filter, butterworth

In filters, Butterworth filter is maximum flat response in pass band and Bessel filter have also flat response then what is the different between them. And how we can choose these filters in practical application?

Comment: No - Bessel response is NOT maximally flat. The damping ratio is larger than for the Butterworth response.

Comment: Bessel doesn't overshoot; Butterworth does. If you need better damped time domain (step) response, or flatter group delay; Bessel. If you need faster frequency domain rolloff : Butterworth or one of the faster types.

Comment: @user_1818839:  Bessel is still underdamped so there is a tiny overshoot although it may be insignificant. Critically damped and over damped is required for no overshoot.

Answer (score 1):

Bessel and Butterworth are different. The differences are more apparent at higher orders. Bessel does not cut as fast but gives better delay performance.

Comment: And in practical application when we use these two